# How to show absolute item but be able to click under it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Sorry, I did not find anything that can help me, so I decided to ask.

What I want to do is pretty straightforward.

I want to have an absolute element (div, icon, etc..) on another div or element.
I want to display the absolute element, but when it gets clicked the item under it gets the click, not the absolute item.

So let's just say I have form input, and I want to have an icon in it with position absolute.
When the icon gets the click, I want the form to be focused.

For some reason, I cannot use the **label** and **for** in this case.

Please guide me to achieve this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use css [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for this:

```
.absolute-item {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: upvoted! :) But I cannot understand how it works! Could you show, please:)

Comment: I love it when I'm looking for some mumbo jumbo code to fix my problem and, someone just put me out of misery with exactly one line of CSS.